# How to fix string overriding when it doesnt extendi to lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I have a class:

```
class point:

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)
```

This works for printing out individual points, but if I have a list of points, the print function isnt overridden. How do I fix this so that the string function prints out what I want even when I have a data structure containing points?